# Haskell @ type annotation

Tags: haskell, types, type-signature

This code seems to use the `@` symbol to annotate a function signature,
 seemingly using it to save the type into a variable?

https://github.com/hlian/mathbot/blob/master/web/src/Main.hs#L63

mathbot cmd@(Just (Command "math" user channel (Just text)))

Attempting to use a similar syntax results in `parse error on input ‘@’`.

Does this do what I think it does? And if so where is it defined come from? And how does one define a function that can operate within a type signature?

Comment: That's not a type annotation, that's a pattern.  The whole thing is called an "as pattern".

Comment: Always include all relevant code. The GitHub code might get deleted.

Comment: You don't "save the type into a variable", that's nonsense. And what is a "function that can operate within a type signature"? (That would seem to speak about dependent types, but I believe you may be referring to entirely something else...)